# Cannot get my variable explorer to work

Tags: python-3.5

I added the variable explorer window in spyder 3 (python 3.5) and nothing is showing up at all when I assign variables or run my code. I added it after typing out my code and when I run it nothing shows up nor when I add any new variables. I am very new and unfortunately do not know what other information would be important in solving this.

[edited to add this image of my spyder application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8VF4.png)

Comment: I am running spyder on my mac. for some reason anaconda keeps crashing when I start it so I have opened spyder directly from the bin folder in my anaconda files if that helps!

Comment: any additional detail on what you're seeing/doing?  are you working within the iPython console with Variable Explorer tab visible?

Comment: @Chris I'm in a beginner level python course in university so I just wrote a very basic program doing math using tuples and lists, subscripting and what not (this all in the editor tab) . the program runs and the printed information is showing up in my ipython console tab. I was in my lab and saw that one of the other students had the variable explorer tab so I figured out how to add it to my window by clicking view, panes, then checking it off. So I have all three of these windows but I can't get the variable explorer to do anything